# Issue in chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to ran any HTML file in chrome.

When I do some changes in the JS code then the chrome doesn't refresh the data.

It is only working if I press 20-25 refresh

I tried also to delete catch.

Do you have any idea how I can fix the refresh at chrome ?

Comment: Ctrl+R should work fine.

Comment: Add a dummy querystring to the end of your js request. Eg. `"abcd.js?t="<?php echo time(); ?>` It is a little harder if you're not using a server side language. Have you tried adding the no cache header?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to clear/bust a cache. This is not a Chrome specific issue.

If your testing in Chrome, I suggest using an [Incognito window](http://www.google.com/goodtoknow/manage-data/incognito-mode/). Incognito windows won't use any stored or cached content and work very well for testing.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome) thread for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

My usual solution is to add a version number to the script link :

```
<script src="thelib.min.js?v=32"></script>
```

I increment the version only when I change the js file. So I'm sure it can be cached if it didn't change and it is updated in browsers having refresh problem (like Chrome).

Comment: I use this method at times too. It's bothersome though when you're authoring a .js file and are making multiple incremental changes that need tested. Pretty soon, you're at `*.js?3789` :)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is pretty notorious for caching stuff. (Part of the reason it's so quick).

As well as the Random number added to the file (As Suggested in an earlier answer). Try turning off the cache via the dev tools.

[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)